# How do I send mail on Google App Engine from user that can't also view the project?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I send mail using Google's mail API without adding that email address to the project? Right now Google says you need to add them as a developer but I don't want the user to see anything about the project.

Example would be a contact form email coming from sales but I don't want sales to find their way into the google dev console and see our costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use services like SendGrid which give you a lot more features than GAE's Mail API.

See a more detailed answer here:
[send email on Google App Engine from custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704888/send-email-on-google-app-engine-from-custom-domain/25707226#25707226)

Comment: Also, you may want to double check this but I think (don't quote me on this) if you add a user as a "Developer" and not as an "Administrator" they would not be able to see anything about billing/costs/etc and you would use their emails via GAE's Mail API. They would still have access to the code/deploying/etc and could break things though...

Comment: I was wanting to just use google services but it looks like it would be too much work. I signed up for a mailgun account and had mail sending in just a few min. It would really be nice to have refined permissions like send email as or upload code only.

Comment: There's a "Viewer" role as well, which doesn't address the concern in the question but might be of interest if you just don't want someone to be able to mess with the app if they stumble across it.  A "can only send email" role might be a good feature request.  Also note that you can send email interactively (but not in a batch job) from the current user. IIRC, this permission is transitive to task queue tasks created by that user, so you could kick off a recurring task with the sales account and use it to send.

Comment: (Or you could just forward email from the sales acct to the dept, and not provide direct access.  That's probably what I'd do.)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new account sales-mailer@whatever that looks like it is coming from sales, but for which only you have access. Then give that account View-only access to your project.

Comment: Creating a new account doesn't fit well at $5 a month for a few emails a week. If this happens to be something that comes up a bunch then we could go that route and setup mail forwards I guess.

Comment: Understood. If you are only putting out a few emails a weeks, you could work something in Apps Script. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)